# When and how should I move deciduous ferns?

Tags: transplanting, propagation, ferns

When is the best time to move a fern? It's a deciduous species, maybe a [shuttlecock fern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matteuccia_struthiopteris). Also can I divide the plant while I'm doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the fern has gone dormant for the season, you can both move and take divisions from it.  It would be best to do this, however, well before the ground freezes, so you can immediately replant the mother plant and your divisions and they have time to recover a bit before the really cold weather sets in.